# How to store the value from text box in another variable using Cypress

Tags: input, textbox, attributes, cypress

name="titleEn" data-testid="edit-category-title-en" type="text" placeholder="Enter category title" value="vxfifyem"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the purpose, there are few ways to do it:

1. Global scope variable: (**BAD PRACTICE**)

```
  let myValue;

  before(()=> {
     cy.get('[data-testid="edit-category-title-en"]').then($el => {
        myValue = $el.text();
     })
  })

  it(()=> {

    cy.log(myValue) // myValue is now available

  })
```

but, as you can see the callback and the variable call cannot be used in the same scope, otherwise the variable will be null.

In case you need it in a common scope, then you can use the [Cypress.Promise](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Syntax) utility, so Cypress will not continue until the promise is resolved.

```
  it('', async () => {
     const myValue = await new Cypress.Promise((resolve) => {
        cy.get('[data-testid="edit-category-title-en"]')
            .invoke('text')
            .then((txt) => resolve(txt.toString()))
     })
  })
  cy.log(myValue) // myValue is available
```

2. Using Cypress Aliases (**BEST PRACTICE**)

I do recommend to go throw documentation first: [Cypress Variables and Aliases](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Return-Values)

```
cy.get('[data-testid="edit-category-title-en"]').invoke('text').as('myValue');
```

then you can call it via: `cy.get('@myValue')`.